# merging files based on column coordinates of two files in python

Tags: python, merge, pandas

I have a file called snp.txt that looks like this:

```
chrom   chromStart  chromEnd    name    strand     observed     
chr1    259         260      rs72477211  +   A/G    single  
chr1    433         433      rs56289060  +   -/C    insertion   
chr1    491         492      rs55998931  +   C/T    single  
chr1    518         519      rs62636508  +   C/G    single  
chr1    582         583      rs58108140  +   A/G    single
```

I have a second file gene.txt

```
chrom   chromStart  chromEnd    tf_title    tf_score
chr1    200         270         NFKB1       123
chr1    420         440         IRF4        234
chr1    488         550         BCL3        231
chr1    513         579         TCF12       12
chr1    582         583         BAD170      89
```

The final output I want is: output.txt

```
chrom   chromStart  chromEnd    name    strand  observed    tf_title    tf_score
chr1    259         260      rs72477211    +    A/G         NFKB1       123
chr1    433         433      rs56289060    +    -/C         IRF4        234
chr1    491         492      rs55998931    +    C/T         BCL3        231
chr1    518         519      rs62636508    +    C/G         TCF12       12
chr1    582         583      rs58108140    +    A/G         BAD170      89
```

The key thing I want to be able to do is to look at gene.txt and check if the rsnumber in the name column of snp.txt is in the same region established by chrom, chromStart and chromEnd.

For example:

In the first row of snp.txt
the rsid rs72477211 is on chr1 between positions 259 and 260.

Now in gene.txt, NFKB1 is also on chr1 but between positions 200 and 270,
this means that rsid rs72477211 is located the NFKB1 region, so this is noted in output txt.

I am unable to do this in using pandas merge function and I'm not sure where to even start.
the files are extremely large so a loop would be highly inefficient.
Can someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it fits in memory, you can [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two dataframes with an `outer` method base only on `chrom` column, then filter your result by doing the range inclusion math:

```
df = snp.merge(gene, how='outer', on='chrom')
df = df[(df.chromStart_x>=df.chromStart_y) & (df.chromEnd_x<=df.chromEnd_y)]
```

You can eventually remove the duplicate columns:

```
del test['chromStart_y']
del test['chromEnd_y']
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain a bit what are you refer to as chromStart_x and y?

Comment: This is how merge works: chromstart and chromend exist in both dataframe, but we merge on name only. It will add suffixes to the duplicated columns in the resulting dataframe. Have a look at merge documentation