# merge dataframe memory efficiency issue pandas

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I am trying to use this exact command for my code

[merging files based on column coordinates of two files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457142/merging-files-based-on-column-coordinates-of-two-files-in-python)

but my system would just freeze (may be because i have ~315,000 lines), any better way to do this?
below is my code:

```
new_df = df.merge(gene_df, how='outer', on ='chrm')
new_df = new_df[(new_df.start_x>=df.start_y) & (df.end_x<=df.end_y)]
print (new_df.head(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `new_df` fields. Your logic uses fields in the original `df` that was previously merged. Carefully, look at your linked question. Such logic across dataframes would be tough to run!

```
new_df = new_df[(new_df.start_x >= new_df.start_y) & (new_df.end_x <= new_df.end_y)]
```

Comment: any alternative approach? most of my upstream and down stream code is in pandas..

Comment: Is your posted code a typo since as is, it should have erred at the suffixed `_x`, `_y`?